# Get all uid that first occurrence in some date

Tags: mysql, indexing

Let's say you have the following table:

```
+-----+-------+---------------------+
| uid | aid   |        time         |
+-----+-------+---------------------+
| 187 | 20021 | 2016-07-19 03:05:06 |
| 167 | 20021 | 2016-07-19 03:05:06 |
| 155 | 20021 | 2016-07-19 03:05:06 |
| 154 | 20021 | 2016-07-19 03:05:06 |
| 155 | 20021 | 2016-07-18 03:05:06 |
| 138 | 20023 | 2016-07-16 05:25:00 |
| 140 | 20021 | 2016-07-16 05:05:18 |
| 153 | 20021 | 2016-07-16 05:04:41 |
| 146 | 20021 | 2016-07-16 05:04:33 |
| 152 | 20021 | 2016-07-16 05:04:27 |
| 151 | 20021 | 2016-07-16 05:04:22 |
| 150 | 20021 | 2016-07-16 05:04:16 |
| 148 | 20021 | 2016-07-16 05:04:10 |
| 147 | 20021 | 2016-07-16 03:29:55 |
| 140 | 20021 | 2016-07-16 02:12:13 |
| 139 | 20020 | 2016-07-16 02:11:53 |
| 154 | 20028 | 2016-07-13 05:04:47 |
| 167 | 20028 | 2016-07-13 05:04:47 |
| 154 | 20028 | 2016-07-12 05:04:47 |
| 137 | 20028 | 2016-07-12 05:04:47 |
+-----+-------+---------------------+
```

The Fast Way to get all uid that first occurrence in some date (perhaps 2016-07-19), but not in before date, using mysql.

The resulting table would be:

```
+-----+-------+---------------------+
| uid | aid   |        time         |
+-----+-------+---------------------+
| 187 | 20021 | 2016-07-19 03:05:06 |
+-----+-------+---------------------+
```

Continue to get **occurrence** in date B and **first occurrence** in date A.

Sample:
Get All uid occurrence in 2016-07-19 and first occurrence in 2016-07-13

```
+-----+-------+---------------------+
| uid | aid   |        time         |
+-----+-------+---------------------+
| 167 | 20021 | 2016-07-19 03:05:06 |
+-----+-------+---------------------+
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: ["Groupwise-max"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/) or MIN, in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the right indexes:

```
select t.*
from t
where time >= '2016-07-19' and time < '2016-07-20' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.uid = t.uid and
                        t2.time < '2016-07-19'
                 );
```

You want indexes on `t(time)` and `t(uid, time)`.

If you just want the `uid` you can also use aggregation:

```
select uid
from t
group by uid
having min(time) >= '2016-07-19' and min(time) < '2016-07-20';
```

I don't think MySQL will use indexes for this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select uid from users
group by uid
having min(date(`time`)) = '2016-07-19
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".